# Boto3 errors out with 'Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"'

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

I am running some python code on an AWS EC2 instance. The IAM role for this EC2 instance has adequate privileges to describe and create new EC2 instances.

My code calls `ec2_client.describe_instances()` and checks whether a specific instance is alive. If that instance is terminated, it will call `ec2_client.run_instances` and create a new instance.

However, when I call `ec2_client.run_instances()`, I get an error `Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"`.

`ec2_client` is a boto3 EC2 client object.

In some other examples, I've seen people getting this error because they had an incorrect region. That is not the case here. I've made sure that the region is correct.

Any ideas why this happens?

I am using `boto3` (1.4.4).

Comment: Can you connect to internet from the EC2 instance? like `ping www.google.com`

Comment: Along those lines, does your security group restrict external access?

Comment: The EC2 instance has outbound access. It's able to ping external servers. I even tried `httping https://ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/` and that works just fine.

Comment: The security group always allowed external access.